# MikTeX mpm does not list custom package

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I'm using MikTeX 21.8

I've created my own package called `garamond.sty` that just tells xelatex to use garamond font. Here's the preamble:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{garamond}
... stuff ...
```

I've put it in the directory

```
C:\Users\melis\Documents\Church\Writing\Style\tex\latex\garamond
```

and added the root to the MikTek directories:
[image]

The documents that depend on the package build perfectly. However, `mpm` does not list the package. This is a problem as TexStudio uses mpm to produce its package list, so TexStudio highlights all the commands as missing as it cannot find the package. (I've got other packages it needs to load, this is just the simplest).

I've tried updating the MikTek file database through the 'Packages' tab in the console and using `mpm --update-db`, and I've run `texhash`, and nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to get MikTek to pick up my custom package and list it in `mpm --list`?

Updated to make the TexStudio symptoms clearer.

Comment: no, mpm lists packages packaged for miktex and not single files. But I doubt very much that syntax listing breaks because of this. Btw: you shouldn't call your package garamond.sty, there is already a sty with this name.

Comment: TexStudio's syntax highlighting is based on its knowledge of existing packages, which is from mpm --list https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/?version=17#miktex

Comment: no this only says that texstudio will then mark a package as missing, and it also says that you can disable the check (which imho is not very useful, if a package is missing you will get a message when the compilation fails).